# HTML5 script tag

Tags: html

I have just seen the following in my book Programming in HTML5 with javascript and css3:

```
<script ref="/file.js"></script>
```

I have never seen the ref attribute tag before in the script tag, is this valid?

Edit:

It is a typo in the book found http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0790145371133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative, `ref` is not a permitted attribute as per: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html

> The script element enables dynamic script and data blocks to be
>   included in documents. Permitted attributes: global attributes & src &
>   defer & async & type & charset & language.
>
> via w3

**Note, "referencing" files in `<script />` tags must be done via the `src` method, which specifies the address of the external script to use.**

I think the author meant to use `src` as below:

```
<script src="/file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. The most likely candidate is the src attribute.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script